# Issues correctly removing childs from flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

hey im having issues removing my enemy blocks. at the moment if i hit everyone of them everything is fine but when i avoid one i get an error message of

> ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
>       at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
>       at EnergyJump/onTick()
>       at flash.utils::Timer/flash.utils:Timer::_timerDispatch()
>       at flash.utils::Timer/flash.utils:Timer::tick()

here is my code i have:

```
public function onTick( timerEvent:TimerEvent ):void 
        {
            //if ranrom number is than than i
            if ( Math.random() < i )
            {
                //place block on stage at location X=550, Y=330
                var randomX:Number = Math.random() * 550;
                var newBlock:Blocks = new Blocks( 550, 335 );
                army.push( newBlock );
                addChild( newBlock );
                //increase speed of spawn
                i = i + 0.0001;
            }

            //move blocks in correct direction
            for each ( var block:Blocks in army ) 
            {
                block.move();
                //if block is hit then remove health and remove child object
                    if ( avatar.hitTestObject( block ) ) 
                    {

                        hp.checkHP(20);
                        army.splice(army.indexOf(block), 1);
                        removeChild( block );

                    }
            }
        }
```

can anyone help me, i dont really know what slice is to be honest or how to use it...

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the documentation for [Array.splice() here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#splice%28%29).

The first argument needs to be the *index* (0, 1, 2 etc.) of the item you want to remove, not the item itself. Flash is trying to read `block` as an integer, but it defaults to 0, so instead of removing the block that has been hit it's just removing the first block in the list. Try this instead:

```
army.splice(army.indexOf(block), 1);
```

I assume you have some code which is clearing any remaining blocks in the list at the end of the game, but because the wrong blocks are being removed from the list it's trying to remove some that were actually hit already.

Comment: i don't currently have it removing if it doesn't hit. it leaves the screen and its gone. should i remove it once it leaves the stage area?

Comment: Also david could i get you to look at this for me. i have 1 more issue that i wish to resolve

Comment: It's a good idea to tidy up things like that, but I don't think it's what was causing your error in that case. Did adjusting your splice help though?

Comment: gave it a try seems to be semi-working but still having issues. seems to remove them but when i hit the next one it creates the same error.

Comment: Hm, that's odd. Are blocks ever added back in to "army", or added to a different parent? It might be worth naming the blocks and tracing out what's happening to make sure it's what you expect, maybe with only a couple of blocks so that it's easier to see.

Comment: i have spent a week on the same problem. cant seem to get passed it. could you have a little look at my file?

Comment: Can you try posting any other code to do with the blocks first? Someone else might be able to spot the problem. I can take a quick look, but I'd probably only be doing the same trace statements as you!

Comment: theres my whole function, take a noisey

Comment: :/ I can't see anything obvious. If you post a link I'll try to take a look at your files later, but if you keep looking for now there must be something causing a difference between `army` and what's actually on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is a corresponding addChild() call for each of those objects that has been made before the call to removeChild()?  There's not enough code being shown, at the moment, to be able to really tell what's going on, but also make sure removeChild() isn't being called more than once on the same object without addChild() being called in between each time.

Comment: thats the only time removechild is being called for that object

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I had a quick look through your files. It's getting a bit off topic for this question, but I'll list the problems I found. In general though you need to look at the parts Flash is complaining about and make sure you're really working with the right variables (eg. if you write `block`, try to make sure you know which `block` Flash is going to look at, and remember that the order matters when you change things.)

It's easy to accidentally remove the wrong items or try to use things that are null, so check each line and think about what each variable actually is at that point (maybe try tracing the variables out too).

- In `avatarEnterFrame` you're checking for blocks that have gone off the side of the screen, but you haven't added a `for each` loop like in `onTick`, so when you use `block` there Flash is looking at your main `public var block:Blocks;` instead of the blocks in `army`.
- In `onPowerTick` you need to adjust your `splice` in the same way as before, so that you remove the `powerups` object you're checking instead of the item at 0.
- In `restartGame` you're setting `gameOverScreen` to null just before trying to remove it, so Flash doesn't know what to remove. Make sure you leave setting it to null until you're done with everything else.

I'll post a separate answer for your game over screen problem so that it's in the right place.